# Embedded C project unable to connect to googleapis.com

Tags: c, geolocation, google-geolocation

I am attempting to use the googleapis.com/geolocation service with an embedded c device (nrf9160 dev kit) to locate that device using the cellular network.

I am currently unable to connect to that website using my device.

I am very new to HTTPs so I may very well be wrong here, but I believe that I need to be provisioned a custom ssl certificate to be able to connect.

How do I get provisioned a certificate?

I have attempted to use a certificate from openssl.com, but that does not seem to have worked.

I have been able to connect to example.com using a certificate that came with the example code that I am modifying.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I have found the solution to my problem.

The google cloud platform has a Certificate Authority Service.

This can be used to issue ssl certificates.